# Why are not all Boost libraries header-only?

Tags: c++, boost

Why are all libraries in Boost not headers-only?
Saying it differently, what makes the use of .lib/.dll mandatory?

Is it when a class can't be a template or has static fields?

Comment: It's mostly the case when the particular module requires platform-specific libs needs to be used. Examples are threads and filesystem.

Comment: `static` class members are a good reason, yes. There are also cases where you just don't want to do it... header only has advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: It is often "does not need to be a template", rather than "can't be a template".

Comment: @Vite Falcon: You can implement filesystem functions portably for different platforms header-only. Header-ony or not is not a question of target platform.

Comment: @phresnel: For whatever reason, boost chose not to. Also from the OP's question, what I gathered was 'Couldn't all of the libs be in headers rather than having to need lib'. From that I infer, why do they have to use cpp/cxx files to create code that generates libs and why couldn't they have those code in header. For that I was reasoning that they need to use platform specific libraries for certain lib and to me they're coding guidelines could have 'Don't include platform specific headers in boost headers'. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Vite Falcon: Ah, my fail, beg your pardon. I was assuming you talked about the general case.

Comment: @Vite Falcon BTW, take a look at the following discussion: http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2011/08/184823.php

Comment: @IgorR. The point you're trying to make?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Different points, I guess.

- Binary size. Could header-only put a size burden on the client?
- Compilation times. Could header-only mean a significant decrease in compilation performance?
- Runtime Performance. Could header-only give superior performance?
- Restrictions. Does the design require header-only?

### About binary size.

*<sup>and a bit of security</sup>*

If there's a lot of reachable code in the boost library, or code about which the compiler can't argue whether it is reachable by the client, it has to be put into the final binary. <sup>(*)</sup>

On operating systems that have package management (e.g. RPM- or .deb-based), shared libraries can mean a big decrease in binary distribution size and have a security advantage: Security fixes are distributed faster and are then automatically used by all .so/.DLL users. So you had one recompile and one redistribution, but *N* profiteers. With a header-only library, you have *N* recompiles, *N* redistributions, always for each fix, and some member of those *N* are huge in themselves already.

<sup>(*) reachable here means "potentially executed"</sup>

### About compilation times.

Some boost libraries are huge. If you would `#include` it all, each time you change a bit in your source-file, you have to recompile everything you `#include`d.

This can be counter-measured with cherry picked headers, e.g.

```
#include <boost/huge-boost-library.hpp> // < BAD
#include <boost/huge-boost-library/just-a-part-of-it.hpp> // < BETTER
```

but sometimes the stuff you really need to include is already big enough to cripple your recompiles.

The countermeasure is to make it a static or shared library, in turn meaning "compile completely exactly once (until the next boost update)".

### About runtime performance.

We are still not in an age were global optimization solves all of our C++ performance problems. To make sure you give the compiler all the information it needs, you can make stuff header-only and let the compiler make inlining decisions.

In that respect, note that inlining gives not always superior performance because of caching and speculation issues on the CPU.

Note also that this argument is mostly with regards to boost libraries that might be used frequently enough, e.g. one could expect `boost::shared_ptr<>` to  be used very often, and thus be a relevant performance factor.

But consider the real and only relevant reason `boost::shared_ptr<>` is header-only ...

### About restrictions.

Some stuff in C++ can *not* be put into libraries, namely templates and enumerations.

But note that this is only halfway true. You can write typesafe, templated interfaces to your real data structures and algorithms, which in turn have their runtime-generic implementation in a library.

Likewise, some stuff in C++ *should* be put into source files, and in case of boost, libraries. Basically, this is everything that would give "multiple definition" errors, like `static` member variables or global variables in general.

Some examples can also be found in the standard library: `std::cout` is defined in the standard as `extern ostream cout;`, and so `cout` basically requires the distribution of *something* (library or sourcefile) that defines it *once and only once*.

Comment: I honestly think only the last part 'About restrictions' answers OP's question :). But a good point about being careful about which headers to include and about runtime performance.

Comment: @ViteFalcon while the last section answers "why can't it be done the other way", other sections provide insight "why header-only libraries might not be the best idea, however technically possible".

Comment: BTW, I'd change "About code size" title to mention compilation times.